# Select the last line of a paragraph using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to create an animation effect on the last line of a paragraph which is wrapped in a div. It has some links in them so it looks a little like this:

```
<div id="wrapper"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu dui et erat</p></div>
```

So where ever the last line break happens on page load, I want to select the last line with a span to give it the effect.

I would love not to have to use jQuery even though I may need to...

Answer (score 2):

while you tagged jquery .. this is a jquery code .. but be sure to include jquery first

```
var parText = $('#wrapper p').text(); // get text of p
var parSplit = parText.split("\n"); // split text by \n
var lastLine = parSplit[parSplit.length-1]; // get last line
parText.replace(lastLine , ''); // replace last line with nothing
$('#wrapper p').append('<span>'+lastLine+'</span>'); // append the last line with `<span>lastline</span>` and give it a style you need
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/uwLjct1z/)

another [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/uwLjct1z/8/) with slideDown effect

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.textContent` `String.prototype.split()` with `RegExp` `/\n/` , `Array.prototype.slice()` with parameter `-1` to select last new line character , `String.prototype.replace()` to replace selected text within `div` with `span` element having selected text

```js
var div = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var text = div.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].textContent.split(/\n/).slice(-1)[0];
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("("+text+")"), "<span>$1</span>")
```

```css
div {
  white-space:pre;
}

div span {
  font-size:18px;
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eu dui et erat</p></div>
```