# Children of an inline element doesn't react the same in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, compatibility

**Chrome**

- Children's width is the equivalent of the content on the last line.
- Children's position is at the bottom of the content box.

**Firefox**

- Children's width is the equivalent of the content box.
- Children's position is at the bottom of the first line.

**Results**
[image]

```css
a {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
  background: #000;
  bottom: -3px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Very Long string that <br> break</a>
```

Anyone have an idea why and how to solve this?

Comment: I might be wrong, but it could be weird rendering caused by placing a `<br>` inside `inline` element... what if you make the anchor an `inline-block`?

Comment: Than the line is full width on both at the bottom, but that kind of look awkward when there is only a small word on the second line. I would like the result to be like in Chrome form both.

Comment: Is it allowed to modify the HTML?

Comment: Ideally no, but what do you have in mind?

Comment: You can wrap the last word(s) in a `span` tag and apply the border to the span, this is the easier way

Comment: But I don't know if only the last word will be on the second line. Depending on the screen resolution.

Comment: How is the BR tag created? would there be more than one BR or only one?

Comment: Can't tell, this will come from a cms.

Comment: Seeing the code that produces the HTML would help a lot! Anyway, I have revised my answer - have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [CSS 2.1 Visual formatting model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) (the same model applies for CSS 3), elements that are rendered in an inline context are rendered with each line as a separate logical block called a *line box*.

Firefox applies relative positioning based on the position and dimensions of the first *line box* (according to the size of the containing block, [as calculated and defined in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block)) which is why you are having this behavior.

The quick and easy solution would be to specify the parent tag's display model to `inline-block`.

---

That said, the specification is not clear on which behavior is the correct one (the logical choice however being Chrome's behavior).

There is currently a bug open at Mozilla for this particular behavior: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=489100

Comment: While this addresses the compatibility issue, it does not produce the effect which the OP is asking for...

Answer (score 0):

Browsers render differently linesbreaks for `inline` elements, you can achieve your desired effect by simply using the `border-bottom` CSS property.

You were trying to use pseudo selectors as borders but they behave differently, they work with the total element's box model with no regard to linebreaks, so another approach is advised.

---

### The CSS `:first-line` way

Right now you cannot target the last line of an element using pure CSS. Your best pure CSS bet is using the psuedo selector `::first-line` which requires the parent to be a `block` / `inline-block` box. Also `::first-line` accepts only a limited number of CSS properties.

**Demo**

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:first-line {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Very Long string that <br> break</a>
```

---

### Getting last line with JS / jQuery

Basically with javascript you could get the string, analyze it, split the last line, wrap last line inside a `span` then append it back.

**Have a look at the example code:**

```
var parText = $('a').text(); // get text of a
var parSplit = parText.split("\n"); // split text by \n
var lastLine = parSplit[parSplit.length-1]; // get last line
parText.replace(lastLine , ''); // replace last line with nothing
$('a').append('<span>'+lastLine+'</span>'); // append the last line with `<span>lastline</span>` and give it a style you need
```

source: [Mohamed-Yousef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578974/select-the-last-line-of-a-paragraph-using-javascript)

---

### Simple CSS span

If you can modify the HTML, this would be the most straightforward way, basically wrap the last line (or text after a `<br>`) inside a span which will get the styling you desire.

**Demo:**

```css
a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
  border-bottom:3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Very Long string that <br> <span>break</span></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Ideally I would need the line to display below the last line of content only and respect that line's width.